# What is a non-decreasing sequence of sets?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, terminology

What is a non-decreasing sequence of sets and how come it can have a limit?

It appear in a probability theory book

Comment: Could it perhaps be a sequence $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset S_3 \dots$?

Comment: http://www.theanalysisofdata.com/probability/A_4.html definition A.4.3

Comment: @AndrewSalmon - What is inside the set and how come the sets could be increasing or decreasing?

Comment: Sets are composed of elements, and the whole concept of a limit here just means that an element is in the limit $\bigcup_n S_n$ if it is eventually in $S_k$ for $k$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon More precisely, a sequence of sets has a limit if every element of the universe is either eventually **in** $S_k$ or eventually **not in** $S_k$, and the limit is the set of elements which are eventually **in**. In other words, $\lim S_k$ is the common value of $\liminf S_k$ and $\limsup S_k$. In other words, the characteristic function of $\lim S_k$ is the pointwise limit (if it exists) of the characteristic function of $S_k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are talking about sets, and you say the sequence is "increasing" or "non-decreasing", it just means that you have the containment $A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset A_{3} \subset \dots \subset A_{n} \subset A_{n + 1} \subset \dots$ (usually, these are all proper subsets if you say "increasing" while they would not all necessarily have to be proper if you say "non-decreasing").

For example, you could take $A_{n} = \{1, 2, \dots, n \}$.  Then $A_{1} = \{1 \}$, $A_{2} = \{1, 2 \}$, $\dots$, and clearly $A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset A_{3} \subset \dots$.  This sequence would be "increasing".

If you take $A_{1} = \emptyset$, $A_{2} = \emptyset$, $A_{3} = \{1 \}$, $A_{4} = \{1 \}$, and $A_{n} = \{ 1 \}$ for all $n \geq 5$, then we have $A_{1} \subseteq A_{2} \subseteq A_{3} \subseteq \dots$.  Since some of the containments are not proper, this sequence would be "non-decreasing".

Comment: Funny that some wrong-headed people don't like to call a sequence $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq\cdots$ "increasing" because some of the sets might be **equal**, oh my, so they call it "non-decreasing" and it doesn't bother them that the sets could be **incomparable**.

Comment: @bof What do you mean the sets could be incomparable?  And who cares what you call it as long as your meaning is clear?

Comment: @bof "it doesn't bother them that the sets could be incomparable" Doesn't it?

Comment: @Did I've noticed that some people will call a sequence $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq\cdots$ a "non-decreasing" sequence. I really have no idea why they use such a convoluted expression instead of just calling it an increasing sequence. Do you?

Comment: @bof Some people call a sequence of real numbers $a_{1} \leq a_{2} \leq a_{3} \leq \dots$ non-decreasing instead of increasing, especially if the inequalities are not all strict.  In some cases with the real numbers, the distinction matters.  Isn't it natural to extend this type of naming to sets?  Also, this still doesn't explain what you meant when you said the sets could be "incomparable" (thanks for ignoring my response to your original comment, by the way).

Comment: @user46944 There's nothing **wrong** with **defining** "increasing" with $\le$ and "strictly increasing" with $\lt$. I understand that some people like to use "non-decreasing" for $\le$ or $\subseteq$ because some of the sequences they want to **include**, notably constant sequences, are "not really increasing". The problem with that is, that some of the sequences they want to **exclude**, such as $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\dots$, are "really non-decreasing". So they really gain nothing, except making themselves harder to read.

Comment: @user46944 What I meant by "the sets could be incomparable" is that sets are not linearly ordered by inclusion; you can have both $S_1\not\subseteq S_2$ and $S_2\not\subseteq S_1$. And making your meaning clear is what I was talking about. It's clearer to call things by what they are rather than what they aren't. It really **doesn't** make your meaning any clearer if you call continuous functions "non-discontinuous functions" or increasing sequences "non-decreasing sequences". IMO.

Comment: @bof The choice is between the pairs of qualifications "nondecreasing"/"increasing" and "increasing"/"strictly increasing".  Each of these pairs seems to be of standard use in some countries, for real valued sequences and, by extension, for set valued sequences, and none of them strikes me as immensely more "convoluted" than the other. In principle, it is true that the qualification "non-decreasing", if applied verbatim to sequences of sets, could include sequences of sets that are "incomparable" (your remark) but I have never seen this confusion occur.

Answer (score 5):

It means that they satisfy $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$.

The limit is not a limit in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ sense. It just means
$\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

For example, take $A_n = [0,n]$, then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = [0, \infty)$.

From a probability perspective, there is a real limit associated with
these nested sets. Suppose $p$ is the probability measure.
Since we have $p A_n \le p A_{n+1} \le 1$, we see that the sequence is non 
decreasing and bounded above and so has a limit. In fact, it is not hard to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} pA_n = p (\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$.

Here is a rather contrived example:

Consider the following probability defined on
measurable subsets of the plane. Let $pA = {1 \over \pi} m(A \cap B(0,1))$. That is, given a subset $A$ of the plane, we measure the area of the overlap
of $A$ and the unit disc $B(0,1)$ and divide the result by $\pi$ to make
it a probability measure.

Let $A_n$ be a regular $2^n$ polygon inscribed in the unit circle and let
$A_{n+1}$ be chosen by adding points in between the existing points. Then
we have $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$, so they are non decreasing (in this case
they can be considered increasing since $A_n \neq A_{n+1}$). Furthermore,
it is clear that the area of the polygons approaches that of the circle,
so we have $pA_n \to 1$.

Comment: What can be inside the set and how come the sets could be increasing or decreasing?

Comment: @AndrewSalmon - Yes, Thank you. copper.hat, may you show me a example for intuition?

Comment: I am not really sure how much intuition an example provides, but I added one. Think of a Venn diagram where each $A_{n+1}$ contains each $A_n$. I added a much more relevant fact (from a probability perspective).

Comment: Literally, "non-decreasing" would mean that "$A_{n+1}$ is not a proper subset of $A_n$" or maybe "$A_m$ is not a proper subset of $A_n$ if $m\gt n$". But a lot of people abuse "non-decreasing sequence" to mean "increasing sequence" and no doubt you're right that that's what's going on here.

Comment: I added a contrived example.

Comment: "Regular $2^n$ polygon", perhaps?

Comment: @Did: Yes indeed, thanks for catching that. Mind blurred by age...