# Limit of nondecreasing and nonincreasing sets

Tags: real-analysis

If $A_n $is nondecreasing, how can I prove that $A_{\infty}$ exists and  and $A_{\infty}$ = $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$.
If $A_n$ is nonincreasing, how can I prove that $A_{\infty}$ exists and $A_{\infty}$ = $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$?

Comment: What definition are you using for $A_\infty$, if not those very expressions?

Comment: By “non decreasing”, do you mean that $A_{n} \subset A_{n+1}$?

Comment: I am only using those expressions. By non decreasing I mean that A_n  can also be equal to A_n+1.

Comment: Also, do we know that all of the $A_n$ are subsets of some set, such as $\forall n, A_n \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ccarvalho, I’ve just never heard ‘nondecreasing’ used for sets, only for functions or sequences of numbers. I understand that they can be equal, but does it mean that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$?

Comment: An is a sequence set.

Comment: Yes, A_n \subset A_{n+1} or  A_n= A_{n+1}

Comment: Ok, I’ve got the answer to my first question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074809/what-is-a-non-decreasing-sequence-of-sets .  Do you have any answer to the second question?

Comment: It is a subset of R.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97862/discussion-between-joe-and-ccarvalho).

Answer (score 1):

To @Greg Martin’s point, how you prove it depends on your definition of $A_{\infty}$.

If your definition is:

$x \in A_{\infty} \leftrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n}(x) = 1$,

Then $x \in A_{\infty} \rightarrow$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n}(x) = 1 \rightarrow$

$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall m>n, x \in A_m \rightarrow$

$x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$,

And $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \rightarrow$

$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in A_n \rightarrow$ (because it’s nondecreasing)

$\forall m \geq n \in \mathbb{N}, x \in A_m \rightarrow$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n}(x) = 1 \rightarrow$

$x \in A_{\infty}$

It would be similar for the second part.